# Position issue on FF but not on Chrome / IE8+

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position

I've been stucked on something for a couple days now. In the website I'm working on, content has to be on an open book with 2 pages. As the pages must have the same height no matter their contents, I used `display: table/ table-cell`. That part works well.

It's the decoration that hurts. On top of each pages there has to be a div with a background-image. I did so with a `position: absolute` div. That works on Chrome / IE8+ but not at all in Firefox, i guess it's because of the table-cell / absolute mix, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what it's suppose to look like :
[image]

And here is how it looks on Firefox :
[image]

Finally, here is a jsfiddle of my html/css structure : http://jsfiddle.net/cd74z/4/

Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally put words on this issue and found a lot of similar answers. This thing is to wrap the `absolute` div with a `relative` one. That seems to do the tricks for everybody (Firefox / Chrome / IE8+)

Here is the updated JSFiddle for those who would like to see how it works : http://jsfiddle.net/cd74z/6/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a problem with absolute positioning whenever tables or `display: table-cell` is involved, where it will ignore the table cells as a relative parent.

It's a 13 year old [Gecko bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895).

You can fix this by reverting from the table structure and using `display: inline-block` on your cells for example, or putting another relative div around your absolute div, as you did.